# No trigger on Lambda when deploying on existing S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers, serverless-framework

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda triggered on a file upload on an **existing** S3 bucket using Serverless Framework.

I managed to have the Lambda deployed but cannot have it triggered by upload on my existing S3 bucket.

---

I am well aware of

- the existence of a `existing` parameter within `serverless.yml`:

```yaml
functions:
  copyToBufferS3:
    handler: handler.copy_to_buffer_s3
    description: Copies newly uploaded technical logs to a buffer S3 bucket
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: my.bucket.name
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: suffix.ext
          existing: true
```

- the fact that such parameter creates another lambda named `<service name>-<stage>-custom-resource-existing-s3`: I can see it in my console (so `existing` parameter and its section actually is taken into account, yay!)
- the importance of indentation in `serverless.yml`: I double checked that parameters under `- s3` section are 4 spaces-indented

---

The problem is: neither of these two lambdas have a trigger set.

How should I edit my serverless.yml (or something else) to actually have my lambda triggered on file upload?

Comment: Did you check the logs of the custom resource?

Comment: @Maurice What do you mean by that? 

There is nothing except "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", "UPDATE_COMPLETE", "UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS" and "UPDATE_COMPLETE" in "Events" section of my newly created stack in CloudFormation console.

Comment: Custom Resources are Lambda functions and usually they are configured to log to CloudWatch ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I just did not have the permission to... display the trigger(s).

I am surprised that in this case, AWS Console displays "Triggers (0)" as if it actually was empty in this section (instead of clearly warning about permission as it usually does).